# Generate random numbers with pre-defined median in Matlab ?

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, median

I am looking for any function or method to create 2D array of random numbers whose median value is predefined like :

```
 array=generateNumbers(medianValue)
```

will return 2D array with median value = medianValue

Is it possible ?

Comment: You can probably check this post to see the algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373200/generate-numbers-in-r

Comment: Do you want normally or uniformly distributed numbers (or something else)? Do you care about the mean? Can the numbers be negative? What bounds do you want (or do you want no bounds)? Esteban's suggestion should be helpful, but if it isn't you will need to answer these question so you can get any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab function `rand` generates (pseudo)-random numbers uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1]. The median of this distribution is 0.5. You can make the median to be `m` by adding `m-0.5` to each number. The function

```
function array = generateNumbers(m, n, medianValue)
  array = rand(m,n)-0.5 + medianValue;
end
```

returns a random matrix of size m by n, taken from a uniform distribution with the given median.

The numbers being random, it is far from certain that the actual median of the generated numbers will be equal to the given median value.

To ascertain a particular median of the selected numbers, you can do the following:

```
function array = generateNumbers(m, n, medianValue)
  array = rand(m,n);
  array = array - median(array(:)) + medianValue;
end
```

---

The related commands in `help rand` point to other distributions available in Matlab.

Comment: Hm. This generates pseudorandom numbers with theoretical expected (mean) value of `median`, but it is not really generating numbers with a predefined median. I suggest clarifying this to the OP and maybe rewriting his question to match the answer, as he seems content with it, but currently this answers a different question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I opted to expand the answer so that it gives both things.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking to simply change the original question, but this is even better. ;-)